# Site for online custom map with tags or labels

Tags: map-making, software-recommendations

I am looking for a site that will do the following for free:

- Allow me to upload a map of a world (either URL or file, I don't
  mind).
- Allow me to tag/label that map, to mark the locations of thing
  (either plain text, or URL links).
- Host the image.

Bonus:

- Let me change/update the image without wiping the tags (as the map
  becomes more detailed)
- Allow multiple people to edit the tags/labels.

Note: I am aware that I could add the information on my own computer and then load the map up to somewhere like imgur. That is my backup plan.
Note 2: Please do not post answers to things that you *think* might work.

Comment: I' moot aware of any but I could quite easily make one if you're willing to wait a week or so

Comment: There is a site that I used a couple of months ago that makes more or less what you are looking for. It closed several weeks later and then reopened but it's not possible to sing in and I'm not sure if the site is still the same. They made a lot of changes it seems. I think it was not free but I'm not 100% sure and this might have changed as well. I can ping the creator of the site for you. He's here.

Comment: Cheers guys :-) That sounds really good. @ArtOfCode that is very generous of you, I am willing to wait.

Comment: @CalWest : Are you still working on Teri Yeri ? http://www.teriyeri.com/#

Comment: He is not really active, so you might want to contact him via something else than SE.

Comment: @Mourdos meta post about this: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/558/ideas-for-a-worldbuilders-mapping-site

Comment: This question is being discussed on meta here: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/563/28

Comment: This question might be worth asking on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: [The site now exists, thanks to ArtofCode.](http://worldbuilders.hol.es/)

Comment: @ArtOfCode Post an answer so I can give you upvotes :-)

Comment: @Mourdos done it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working free map editors as of today include:

- [Inkarnate](https://inkarnate.com/)
  *signup required. Has been in "Beta" for years.

  Example image from the [Inkarnate main page](https://inkarnate.com/)*
  [image: Inkarnate map example]
- [Worldspinner](https://worldspinner.com/)
  *signup required. usability not tested, but free and online.

  Example images from the [Worldspinner gallery](https://worldspinner.com/gallery/)*
  [image: Worldspinner interior example]
  [image: WOrldspinner exterior example]
- [RollForFantasy](http://rollforfantasy.com/tools/map-creator.php#contentContainer)
  *no labels, added only to give more options in case others go offline.

  Example image randomly generated.*
  [image]

---

Feel free to alter this list as new options arise or old ones go down. I only looked into online map editors here, there might be suitable ones that need local installation.

Answer (score 4):

Use Google Drive. When you create a new document, click 'more' and you have the option to create a **Google Drawings** document.  You can insert your map as a picture (upload or URL) and then make the labels using text boxes.  The labels can be freely edited and changes will show up real-time to viewers.

You can control access so that the document is publicly viewable.  Click the 'Share' button in the upper-right hand corner and then click 'Get shareable link.'  All you have to do is give someone the link and they will be able to see your map!  You can then enable editing either for all viewers or just for a few specified accounts.

Hope this helps!